# how to scroll to an anchor on the page after a confirm with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form that is very long and I need the javascript which catches an error and displays a "confirm " window to return the user to the middle of the form, not the top of hte page.
However no matter what I try (using the $"#link").focu for instance. the page always returns to the top of the page.

I would like it to go to an anchor I have on the page.

Comment: Can you share an example with us? your javscript and a sample HTMl?

Comment: `$("body, html").animate({'scrollTop': $(document).height()/2}, 500 );` ?

Comment: Use anchor tag and set href to #link

Answer (score 1):

Without even using any extra JavaScript, we can do this way:

```
<a href="#middle" onclick="return confirm('Shall we make a move ?');">Go to middle!</a>
```

**Snippet**

```html
<div id="top">Top</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="middle">Middle</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="bottom">
  <a href="#middle" onclick="return confirm('Shall we make a move ?');">Go to middle!</a>
</div>
```

The good part about `return` inside a `click` event will accept `true` or `false`, something like what `confirm` gives. So, if you wanna follow the link, then it needs a `true`, which will happen when you give `OK` to the `confirm`.

Answer (score 0):

- Attach `click` event over `a` element
- Use `confirm-dialogue` to ask user-input
- Use `evene.preventDefault()` if user says `NO`

```js
$('#bottomAElem').on('click', function(e) {
  var c = confirm('Shall we make a move ?');
  if (!c) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">Top</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="middle">Middle</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="bottom">
  <a href="#middle" id='bottomAElem'>Go to middle!</a>
</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/au8a5cwL/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit over kill (actually, way overkill), but you can use it for other stuff as well.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lddyn573/3/

HTML

```
            <a class="full" href="#section1">#section1</a>
            <a class="full" href="#section2">#section2</a>
            <a class="full" href="#section3">#section3</a>
            <a class="full" href="#section4">#section4</a>
            <a class="full" href="#section5">#section5</a>


<div class="body">

  <div class="divider" id="section1">
    <h2>Section 1</h2></div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div class="divider" id="section2">
    <h2>Section 2</h2></div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div class="divider" id="section3">
    <h2>Section 3</h2></div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div class="divider" id="section4">
    <h2>Section 4</h2></div>
  <div>

  </div>
  <div class="divider" id="section5">
    <h2>Section 5</h2></div>
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
```

JQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      // Add smooth scrolling to all links
      $("a").on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
          // Prevent default anchor click behavior
          event.preventDefault();

          // Store hash
          var hash = this.hash;

          // Using jQuerys animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 20
          }, 800, function() {

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        } // End if
      });
    });
```